How to use volumes inside Devcontainers
I'm learning devcontainers in docker and i have do this devcontainer.json :
{
    "name": "Node Dev Container",
    "dockerComposeFile": "compose.yml",
    "service": "dev",
    "workspaceFolder": "/home/node/app",
    "shutdownAction": "stopCompose"
}

It was associate with this compose.yml :
services:
  dev:
    image: node:latest
    volumes:
      - ../node:/home/node/app

Everything are fine but my volume associate /home/node/app in my container are associate with all my project folder and not only the node folder like as expected.
My project structure
|.devcontainer
  -|devcontainer.json
  -|compose.yml
|node
  -|index.js
|readme.md


Since compose.yml is in the .devcontainer directory, it looks like the relevant pathing is correct.   Are you running  docker compose ... in the directory above .devcontainer?
For debugging, you may want to experiment with an absolute path to the node folder to make sure everything is solid: ```volumes:

/absolute/path/to/your/project/node:/home/node/app```


I dont run docker compose and i let my ide (webstorm) identify my compose.yml with my devcontainer.json. But when i only start the container by running docker compose and without my devcontainer.json, my volume are well as expected. Also, an absolute path change nothing.

I added the webstorm tag to invite more webstorm users to help out.  I don't use that editor.  A quick websearch turned up instructions on how to set the mappings in a similar editor (phpstorm) ... but it would be nice for another webstorm user to tagup: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-38629/Wrong-path-opt-project-detected-for-docker-volume
